# Write txt file by url-ftp

Tags: python

I started to programing in python and I'm stuck... ocr-apk on my mobile phone sends csv data by ftp connection to PC... ocr-apk create basketball scoreboard data with live time.. my code needs to write txt file with last time in csv file (for OBS studio)... my code write time only when I pres F5 and stop, is not following cvs new updated times... I try with (while True: and time.sleep(1) but code makes a mess in OBS... how to solve this problem, to my code see the entry of new times data in csv and makes writing last live time?

***CSV data:***

```
DDR_20210717_162246.csv
time[sec],data[xxxx]
0.0,
1.0,12:00
2.0,11:59
3.0,11:58
4.0,11:57
5.0,11:56
6.0,11:55
7.0,11:54
8.0,11:53
9.0,11:52
10.0,11:51
11.0,11:50
12.0,11:49
13.0,11:48
```

***My code:***

```
import csv
import os
import urllib.request
import codecs
             
url = "ftp://192.168.0.102:2221/DDReaderWork/DDR_20210727_012557.csv"
ftpstream = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
csvfile = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(ftpstream, 'utf-8'))

for line in csvfile:
    outFileName="OBStime.txt"
    outFile=open(outFileName, "w", encoding='utf-8')
    outFile.write(line[-1])
    outFile.close()
```

Comment: F5? You're running code in IDLE?? Show what you tried with the while loop if you want the code to run every second

Comment: yes in IDLE and code is show result one time so code is ok but I don't know what to make next to work perfect... and I tryit this code, but I make partial successfully result

`import time
while True:
 #CODE 
time.sleep(1)`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by partial? For example, you are opening and closing your outFile for each line in the csvfile. so only the last line is going to get written

Comment: Yes, if I run one time is show me one live time in that moment without following number in csv... If I input 'while True:' is working, but numbers is not correct in 50% cases, sometimes showing wrong numbers or without reading numbers... I dont know whats happening... I make a code to csv read from PC and everything working perfect withhout any problem... it is possible the network make problems...who knows

Comment: If you really want to read a FTP file periodically, one second is far too quick, IMO. 3-5 would be better... But still, you should open and close the file _outside_ of the `for line in csvfile` loop, or better use `with open(..., "w") as f...: (indent) for line in csvfile: (indent) f.write(line[-1])`

Answer (score 0):

I finded solution, this code working perfect... guys, thanks on help

```
while True:

    from urllib import request

    url = "http://192.168.0.102:8080/DDR_20210728_211057.csv"
    response = request.urlopen(url)
    line = response.read().decode('latin-1')

                

    outFileName="OBStime.txt"
    outFile=open(outFileName, "w")
    outFile.write(line[-7:])
    outFile.close()
```